# How to extract values from UL and LI?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup, however I am unable to get the value in each

. I want to get the value "Phnom Penh" and "full-time"

```
<ul class="key-list">
    <li class="clearfix">
        <span class="key">
        <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Location: 
        </span>
        <span class="value">Phnom Penh</span>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="key">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
     Schedule: </span>
    <span class="value">Full-time</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: directly find_all() spans of class value!?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Simplified title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

text = '''<ul class="key-list">
    <li class="clearfix">
        <span class="key">
        <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Location: 
        </span>
        <span class="value">Phnom Penh</span>
    </li>
    <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="key">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
     Schedule: </span>
    <span class="value">Full-time</span>
    </li>
</ul>'''

soup = Soup(text, 'html5lib')

vals = soup.find_all('span', {'class', 'value'})

for x in vals:
    print(x.text)
```